# How to cause std::mktime to fail?

Tags: c++, gcc, 64-bit

I used [std::mktime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime) to set/get time in my program. The man page tells:

> The values in time are permitted to be outside their normal ranges.

and also that it returns -1 if it can not represent the result as std::time_t

I tried everything in my unit tests to make this function fail, but without a success.
[These](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96ec1b25ebc13473) are just some attempts:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    setenv("TZ", "/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York", 1); // POSIX-specific

    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    std::tm tm = *std::localtime(&t);
    std::cout << "Today is           " << std::put_time(&tm, "%c %Z")
              << " and DST is " << (tm.tm_isdst ? "in effect" : "not in effect") << '\n';
    tm.tm_year = 550;
    tm.tm_year = 123456789;
    tm.tm_mon = 88;
    tm.tm_mday = 200;
    //tm.tm_mon -= 100;  // tm_mon is now outside its normal range
    std::mktime(&tm);  // tm_dst is not set to -1; today's DST status is used
    std::cout << "100 months ago was " << std::put_time(&tm, "%c %Z")
              << " and DST was " << (tm.tm_isdst ? "in effect" : "not in effect") << '\n';
}
```

So, how do I set parameters to make this function fails?

---

As suggested in comments, [I tried INT_MAX](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc4adfd0c4ad771f) and it still doesn't fail. So,  this:

```
tm.tm_year = std::numeric_limits< decltype( tm.tm_year ) >::max();

    if ( -1 == std::mktime(&tm) )
        std::cout << "std::mktime() failed)" << '\n';
```

is still not going to make it fail.

---

```
$CXX --version
aarch64-pdm3-linux-g++ (GCC) 6.4.0
```

Comment: If you change year for example to `INT_MAX`, `std::mktime` will return -1. It's a long time from now, but the date you are using now as an example can still be represented...

Comment: @Elijan9 thanks, but it didn't make it fail. check the edit. It does print negative value tho

Comment: Well failing is returning -1, what do you mean by fail?

Comment: [std::mktime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime) tells:  "Return: Time since epoch as a std::time_t object on success or -1 if time cannot be represented as a std::time_t object." --- I want to get -1 as the result of the function call.

Comment: @BЈовић Exactly, you need to check the **return** **value**, it will be -1 when `mktime` is unable to make a valid time (e.g. when it overflows).

Comment: @Elijan9 "if ( -1 == std::mktime(&tm) )"  this should be a check (check my edit). It still doesn't get triggered.

Comment: Yes it does, see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83975030c3455ae8

Comment: @Elijan9 My compiler is 64 bit, therefore your max int value doesn't make it fail in my case. And as you said, INT_MAX should make it fail, yet it doesn't. Why using limit's max value didn't make it fail as in my edit?

Comment: @BЈовић 64 bit shouldn't matter, according to the C standard, tm_year is still an int, so it should still be limited between INT_MIN and INT_MAX. limit's max value didn't work because it still didn't overflow unless you add more than a year using the month/day arguments. If it doesn't overflow, the date can still be represented. See my answer.

Comment: @Elijan9: It matters since `time_t` can reasonable be 64 bits even on systems where `INT_MAX` is 32 bits. Since there are far less than 2^32 seconds in a year, any 32 bits year can be converted into a 64 bits time in seconds.

Comment: I assumed it will fail if it can't update the `tm` struct, even if the given date *can* be expressed int `time_t`. Apparently that is implementation dependent even between 64 bit compilers...

Answer (score 2):

Your sample does fail for the suggested input `std::numeric_limits< decltype( tm.tm_year ) >::max()`.  Your sample does not check for the -1 return value. If you add

```
auto err = std::mktime(&tm);  // tm_dst is not set to -1, err is.
```

`err` is set to -1 for this input.

You can see the failure at https://ideone.com/GUcM3N

You can also see the failure at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8288579ec8924d7e

Output is identical on both services:

```
Today is           Thu Apr 19 09:07:40 2018 EDT and DST is in effect
100 months ago was Thu ? 200 09:07:40 -2147481749 EDT and DST was in effect
-1
```

Comment: I do the check (see the example in my edit). Why it works on ideone and not on coliru and with my compiler?

Comment: @BЈовић  coliru also fails with the given sample.

Answer (score 1):

`mktime` will fail to update a `tm` struct when an overflow occurs, e.g. when year is set to `INT_MAX` and more than 12 months are added (over a year). Like this:

```
std::tm tm;
tm.tm_year = INT_MAX;
tm.tm_mon = 13;
std::time_t rc = std::mktime(&tm);
```

It will also fail to update a `tm` struct if you set the year to `INT_MIN`, the month to zero and subtract one day (set `tm_mon` to 0 and `tm_mday` to -1):

```
std::tm tm;
tm.tm_year = INT_MIN;
tm.tm_mon = 0;
tm.tm_mday = -1;

std::time_t rc = std::mktime(&tm);
```

It will *not* fail when year is set to `INT_MAX` if the combination of month and tm_mday is still less than a year, since that is still representable!

However as MSalters mentions this won't always result in a -1 as return value. Sometimes `mktime` will return -1 when it cannot normalize the time-stamp to a valid `tm` struct. But depending on the implementation `mktime` could also only return a -1 when the time cannot be expressed in `time_t` (which could be never since time_t is "unspecified"). In the latter case it is actually dangerous to assume the tm struct is normalized to a valid value.

Comment: Technically this is not guaranteed to fail; you can't assume a particular implementation. An implementation may very well use 64 bits for all behind-the-scenes calculation, and cast `tm_year` to 64 bit prior to any operation.

Comment: I just build and installed a 32-bit gcc compiler, and it fails when I use INT_MAX. But 64-bit, I can not make to fail. It never returns -1

Comment: @MSalters AFAIK technically it will fail since tm_year is defined to be an `int` by the standard and INT_MAX to be the maximum value that data type can hold? (However it may be possible that mktime won't notice the overflow.)